# Corrputed my Intel video drivers 12.04

Tags: drivers, video, intel

I have a Lenovo W520 with nVidia Optimus and an Intel Sandybridge Mobile GT2+ (according to X log) on 12.04 and after installing bumblebee it was all working fine (apart from the nVidia card appearing to be a bit slower than the Intel one).

Then I tried to get it working with multiple monitors, which was a huge mistake.  I tried a few howtos, taking care to back them out when they failed.  However I tried this one:

http://sagark.org/optimal-ubuntu-graphics-setup-for-thinkpads/

Which involves patching the Intel driver, and it worked a bit but not well enough.  So I tried backing it out and now nothing OpenGL related works under the Intel card.  Glxgears hangs X with the 'i915 stuck on render ring' message.  OpenGL stuff works fine using primus.

Most people with Intel freeze issues seem to experience periodic freezes - my system works fine indefinitely as long as I don't run anything using OpenGL.  I've tried reinstalling the intel driver package, mesa utils, and everything I can find to relate to the driver and opengl, but nothing makes a difference.  The unity-test thing reports 3D is supported so Unity 3D will attempt to start, then hang on login.

Seems like simply reinstalling the driver should have put it back to its original working condition...?

Answer (score 0):

Intel has greatly improved its support for Linux, and they put together a nice project which can be found [here](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads). You can download and install **Intel(R) Graphics Installer for Linux**, either the 32bit version or the 64bit version, and test it for your Intel video card. They named it Graphics Installer for Ubuntu* 13.10 but it should work for Ubuntu 12.04 too.

Comment: Unsatisfied dependencies:

 intel-linux-graphics-installer depends on libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.37.3); however:
  Version of libglib2.0-0 on system is 2.32.4-0ubuntu1.
 intel-linux-graphics-installer depends on libpackagekit-glib2-16 (>= 0.8.10); however:
  Package libpackagekit-glib2-16 is not installed.

Looks like 12.04 is too old for this.  Which is annoying - the reason I've installed it is because it's long term support - not from Intel it seems.

Comment: Yes, they say the installer is aimed to Ubuntu 13.10. Using Ubuntu 12.04 is rather fortunate for you because you don't have to experience some very annoying issues other guys have with this new Ubuntu 14.04, overheating included. Your system may freeze but it does not overheat your hardware.